# Counting elements of a vector in a row in the table

Tags: r, vector, dplyr, counter

I have the following problem. Suppose I have a column in the data frame, the values in one column are vectors and for each row of data I would like to count the number of elements in that particular vector, eg.

```
ID, brands
1, c("brand1", "brand2", "brand3")
2, c("brand4")
3, c("brand5", "brand7")
```

and using dplyr I would like to add 'counter' column which tells me how many elements has particular vector in the row, eg.

```
ID, brands, counter
1, c("brand1", "brand2", "brand3"), 3
2, c("brand4"), 1
3, c("brand5", "brand7"), 2
```

I used `counter = length(brands)` but it gives the total number of rows in the frame.

Comment: Please use `dput()` to provide a reproducible example of your data as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: `dplyr::n_distinct(brands)` ?

Comment: for daTA - 
`df <- data.table(ID = c(1,2,3), brands = c(c('brand1, brand2, brand3'),
                                                     c('brand4'),
                                                     c('brand5, brand7')))`

Comment: `n_distinct(brands)` returns the total number of rows, the same result I have with `lenght(brands)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lengths` instead of `length`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID=1:3, 
  brands=I(list(
    c("brand1", "brand2", "brand3"),
    c("brand4"),
    c("brand5", "brand7")
  ))
)
df$n <- lengths(df$brands)           
df
# ID       brands n
# 1  1 brand1, .... 3
# 2  2       brand4 1
# 3  3 brand5, .... 2
```

Comment: @J_F, what comments? OP seems to have a list-column

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.